# Using Spark and R for trending detection in time series

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, anomaly-detection

I am new to both R and to Spark, but I am trying to create a scalable R application to detect increasing/decreasing query executed by users.

I have a Spark DataFrame containing data in the following format:

```
+-------+------------------------+-------------------------+
| user  |         query          |       query_time        |
+-------+------------------------+-------------------------+
| user1 | Hp tablet              | 2011-08-21T11:07:57.346 |
| user2 | Hp tablet              | 2011-08-21T22:22:32.599 |
| user3 | Hp tablet              | 2011-08-22T19:08:57.412 |
| user4 | hp laptop              | 2011-09-05T15:33:31.489 |
| user5 | Samsung LCD 550        | 2011-09-01T10:28:33.547 |
| user6 | memory stick           | 2011-09-06T17:15:42.852 |
| user7 | Castle                 | 2011-08-28T22:06:37.618 |
+-------+------------------------+-------------------------+
```

This dataset has hundreds of thousand of rows. I need to be able to visualise somehow that, for example, "hp tablet" is trending up.

I have looked at some libraries (e.g. [Breakout Detection](https://github.com/twitter/BreakoutDetection), [Anomaly Detection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87946/r-detect-increasing-decreasing-trend-of-time-series)) that could help me achieve this, but I do not know if they play well with Spark. And if they do, I couldn't find any examples on how to go about the programming.

I'm using R version 3.4.0 and SparkR version 2.1.0, running on a Zeppelin Notebook.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am also open to any other approaches.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
%r
#created a sparkR dataframe
df_query <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(query = c("Hp tablet","Hp tablet","Hp tablet","hp laptop", "Samsung LCD 550 "), 
query_time = c("2011-08-21T11:07:57.346","2011-08-21T22:22:32.599","2011-08-22T19:08:57.412","2011-09-05T15:33:31.489","2011-09-01T10:28:33.547")))

#remove T as its not a timestamp format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
df_query_1 <- select(df_query, df_query$query, regexp_replace(df_query$query_time, '(T)', ' '))
+----------------+--------------------------------+
|           query|regexp_replace(query_time,(T), )|
+----------------+--------------------------------+
|       Hp tablet|            2011-08-21 11:07:...|
|       Hp tablet|            2011-08-21 22:22:...|
|       Hp tablet|            2011-08-22 19:08:...|
|       hp laptop|            2011-09-05 15:33:...|
|Samsung LCD 550 |            2011-09-01 10:28:...|
+----------------+--------------------------------+

df_query_1 <-  rename(df_query_1, query_time=df_query_1[[2]])

#registering temp table:
registerTempTable(df_query_1, "temp_query")
```

Visualizing from temp table created above:

```
%sql
select * from temp_query
```

screen 1[image]

screen 2: visualize as bar graph[image: visualize as bar graph]

Comment: Hi @Arun, thank you very much for your detailed answer.
Because I am new to Spark, this already helps me to understand some things, but I think it does not answer my original question.

I need to be able to tell which queries are gaining popularity over time, so the X-axis should be the time series. I was thinking that maybe [this Breakout Detection library](https://github.com/twitter/BreakoutDetection) will do the trick, but I don't know how to use it together with SparkR.

Answer (score 0):

For using library(AnomalyDetection), the data should be in this format

```
head(raw_data)
                timestamp   count
14393 1980-10-05 13:53:00 149.801
14394 1980-10-05 13:54:00 151.492
14395 1980-10-05 13:55:00 151.724
14396 1980-10-05 13:56:00 153.776
14397 1980-10-05 13:57:00 150.481
14398 1980-10-05 13:58:00 146.638
```

if your query_time is X-axis how will you define Y-axis in numeric, and in `2011-08-21T11:07:57.346` what `T` means, is that time taken is `11:07:57.346`. Need more clarification